# How to use is / as in procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I use sql server, and have just switched to oracle. When I got to the procedure, I had a few questions with "IS / AS". I don't know when to use "IS" and when to use "AS". Please help me! 
Thanks end respect.

sql navigator 7.1

Answer (score 2):

**The PL/SQL language evolved such the the "IS" and "AS" operators are equivalent.**

Functionally the **"IS"** and **"AS"** syntax performs identical functions and can be used interchangeably.

However, in SQL there is a subtle difference between "AS" and "IS":

```
SQL> create or replace view emp_view as select * from scott.emp ; 
View created. 

SQL> create or replace view emp_view is select * from scott.emp ; 
ERROR at line 1: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: ohh, thank you so much.